# How to vertically align absolutely positioned images on top of one another?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of images that I want to use to create an image fader, the images could be any size so I want to set them up in such a way that all images are stacked one on top of each other dead center to their parent container but not completely sure how to achieve this, if anyone could suggest how I do this that would be great.

**CSS**

```
.logo-fader {
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.logo-fader > li {
    /* opacity: 0; */
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s linear;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
}

.logo-fader > li.show-logo {
    opacity: 1;
}

.logo-fader > li img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/s7J2V/1/

Basically if I add position absolute to the list item then this cancels out the inline-block which vertically aligns the images

Comment: What exactly is the issue? If it works currently, why do they need to be absolutely positioned? Or is the fiddle *not* what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the fiddle isnt want im trying to achieve, basically i need each image to be positioned on top of one another and dead center of the grey area

Comment: Ah, I understood stacked to mean the way they were currently positioned. Centered vertically and horizontally, correct?

Comment: yeah thats it sorry for the misleading explanation! yeah so vertically aligned one on top of another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose each image in a container div, with 100% width and height, position absolute.
center the image in the container div.
now, the div are stacked one on another, use the fade on the container divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="FaderHolder">
    <div class="ImgContainer">
        <span class="Centerer"></span>
        <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="ImgContainer">
        <span class="Centerer"></span>
        <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="ImgContainer">
        <span class="Centerer"></span>
        <img src="..."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#FaderHolder
{
    /*YOUR CSS*/
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.ImgContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.ImgContainer > img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centerer
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

the trick for verticaly centering the img, is using the "Centerer" span, as shown.
(if you want an explanation for why this works, let me know..)

Comment: hey, this doesnt achieve what I need. have you an example

Comment: the images aren't vertically aligned when I use your code http://jsfiddle.net/dAgaE/

Comment: I forgot a '%' after the '100' in the height.

Comment: and, you have to fix a height and width to '#FaderHolder'

Comment: sorry still not working http://jsfiddle.net/dAgaE/6/ can you please update my fiddle?

Comment: and last fix for today, in the '.Centerer', change 'width:100%' to 'height:100%'.

Comment: For more semantic HTML, drop the spans and just use a pseudo element instead: http://jsfiddle.net/dAgaE/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
logo-fader > li {
    /* opacity: 0; */
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s linear;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
}
```